# Error with posting to a wall when a user creates a new post

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

For some reason I can't get this script to run when I add the wallTable() function. When I remove the wallTable() function the script executes just fine... What I am trying to do is append the wallTable() function to '#load_status out' whenever the ajax json request returns true. Any help?

```
function wallTable(firstname, lastname, defaultImgURI, entryData, entryCreationDateTime) {
     return '<table id="load_status_out" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 500px; height: 75px" class="status-border-bottom-box1">
     <tr>
     <td valign="top" rowspan="3" style="width: 61px">
     <img style="padding: 3px" id="defaultImg a0" src="' + defaultImgURI + '" width="59" height="64" />
     </td>
     <td valign="top" class="text-align-left" style="padding: 3px; height: 25px;">
     <a class="font1">' + firstname + '" "' + lastname + '</a>
     &nbsp;</td>

     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td class="font1" valign="top" class="font1" style="padding: 3px; height: 25px;">
     ' + entryData + '</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td valign="top" class="style1" style="padding: 3px; height: 25px; width: 433px;">
     <a class="link-font1" id="like" href="#" style="width: 138px">Like</a>
     <span class="font2"> | </span>
     <a id="comment" href="#" style="width: 138px" class="link-font1">Comment</a>
     <span class="font2"> | ' + entryCreationDateTime + '</span>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>';

function postToWall(firstname, lastname, defaultImgURI, entryData, entryCreationDateTime) {
        var updater = $("#updater").val();
        var dataString = '&updater=' + updater;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/postToWall",
            data: dataString,
            json: {postedToWall: true},
            success: function(data) {
            if(data.postedToWall == true) {
                var html = wallTable(dat.firstname, data.lastname, data.defaultImgURI, data.entryData, data.entryCreationDateTime);
                $(html).prependTo("#load_status_out").slideDown("slow");
            } else if(data.postedToWall == false) {
                return false;
            }
          }
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem seems to be in this line:
`var html = wallTable(dat.firstname, data.lastname, data.defaultImgURI, data.entryData, data.entryCreationDateTime);`
 it should be
 `var html = wallTable(data.firstname, data.lastname, data.defaultImgURI, data.entryData, data.entryCreationDateTime);`